# Social authentication - better to do on FE or BE side?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

If we want to do social authentication (for example *Facebook* or *Google*), then which side is best to integrate it. Backend side or front end side? For back-end we have *NodeJS*, in which we can use *PassportJS* to do it and for front end side we have *Angular2.0* for which there are plugins to do it as well. I am a bit confused on which side this code should reside. If anyone has any view on this then please let me know.

Comment: Both sides =) The authToken you store should placed in your backend while the session interaction could be done with the FE.

Comment: Check Salih answer, he is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are trying to implement Oauth2 and actually it depends on your application requirements.

For Example if you will follow the Oauth2 Authorization with `Authorization Code Flow` You need to implement Authorization on both client and server side.

But, if you will follow the Oauth2 Authorization with `Implicit Flow` You need to implement Authorization on just client side.

My recommendation is to read this for details about Oauth2 flows [Oauth2 Flows Explained](https://alexbilbie.com/guide-to-oauth-2-grants/)

> **Implicit grant (section 4.2)**
>
> The implicit grant is similar to the
>   authorization code grant with two distinct differences.
>
> It is intended to be used for user-agent-based clients (e.g. single
>   page web apps) that can’t keep a client secret because all of the
>   application code and storage is easily accessible.
>
> Secondly instead of the authorization server returning an
>   authorization code which is exchanged for an access token, the
>   authorization server returns an access token.